# Build Error on importing images with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-4

I import images like this below:

```
import StepIcon from '../../public/images/icon_step.png'
```

and it works with no problem but when I run build I get the error below, guess I gotta fix webpack setting but I have no idea. how can i solve this problem?

**Error**

```
 error  in ./public/images/icon_step.png

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/file-loader/dist/cjs.js):
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be one of type string, Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received type function
    at Hash.update (internal/crypto/hash.js:64:11)
    at getHashDigest (/mnt/c/Users/wbvco/Desktop/Project Baby/styled-react-boilerplate/node_modules/loader-utils/lib/getHashDigest.js:48:8)
    at url.replace (/mnt/c/Users/wbvco/Desktop/Project Baby/styled-react-boilerplate/node_modules/loader-utils/lib/interpolateName.js:96:11)
    at String.replace (<anonymous>)
    at Object.interpolateName (/mnt/c/Users/wbvco/Desktop/Project Baby/styled-react-boilerplate/node_modules/loader-utils/lib/interpolateName.js:93:8)
    at Object.loader (/mnt/c/Users/wbvco/Desktop/Project Baby/styled-react-boilerplate/node_modules/file-loader/dist/index.js:27:36)

 @ ./src/components/signupstep.js 35:0-57 511:11-19
 @ ./src/pages/signup.js 
 @ ./src/app.js
 @ ./src/index.js
 @ multi react-hot-loader/patch ./src/index.js
```

**webpack Setting**

```
{
                    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/i,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'url-loader',
                            options: {
                            limit: 8192,
                            },
                        }]
                },
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's due to image relative path issue, can you try the below methods.

1. Simple method you should follow, see [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/) for more info.
2. By using webpack

Please update the webpack like below

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.(jpe?g|gif|png|svg)$/i,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 10000
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
},
```

Then you can import the images from public folder to react component

```
import image from '../../public/assets/images/logo.png'

<img src={image}/>
```

3. By using require method
4. Also you can try this by install url-loader and file-loader

   npm install url-loader file-loader --save-dev

Then update the webpack config as

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192' }
    ]
}
```

and finally

```
<img src={require('./PATH_TO_IMAGE/IMAGE.png')}/>
```